# variable assignment before vs after make command

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

`make` can take variable assignments as part of his command line. Is `DEBUG=1 make` the same as `make DEBUG=1`? With this simple Makefile, both print `echo 1`.

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
        echo ${DEBUG}
```

It's clear in the latter case, `DEBUG=1` is part of the argument to `make`, but the first one only seems like a variable assignment in shell. So I'd assume `make` gets the value differently. Some clarification about the difference will be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is `DEBUG=1 make` the same as `make DEBUG=1`?

Not really.

- In `DEBUG=1 make`: `make` obtains the variable from the *environment*. That is, the shell sets the variable `DEBUG`, then `make` is executed and it (the process running `make`) inherits that environment variable.
- In `make DEBUG=1`: `make` obtains the variable from the *command line* (i.e.: `make` sets the variable itself).

---

#### Relevant differences

Variables obtained from the command line *override* the variables obtained from the environment. That is, in:

```
DEBUG=0 make DEBUG=1
```

`DEBUG` is `1`, not `0`.

Note as well that variables obtained from the command line *override* the variables set inside the makefile (unless the [`override`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html) directive is used), whereas environment variables don't (unless the option [`-e` or `--environment-override`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) is passed to `make`).

Therefore, if the makefile sets a variable named `DEBUG` as in the following:

```
DEBUG = 0
all:
    @echo ${DEBUG}
```

Then:

```
make DEBUG=1
```

echoes `1`, whereas:

```
DEBUG=1 make
```

echoes `0`.

---

#### The `origin` built-in function

You can use the [`origin`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html) built-in function to find out where a variable comes from. Consider this modification of your makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
    @echo DEBUG is from $(origin DEBUG)
```

Then:

```
$ make DEBUG=1
DEBUG is from command line
```

but:

```
$ DEBUG=1 make
DEBUG is from environment
```